# Replacing Enum constants with static variable fetched from table

Tags: java, spring, enums

Dealing with an old enum class which contains group of constants. A function inside enum class is defined to check if a passed constant is present in the enum or not. 
Now there can be some constants that may be added to enum. If so it has to go through separate release process. 
So we want to get rid of enum and get data from db or from a property file so that any new addition need not go through release.
But there is a problem with it. There are too many modules referring to the enum, hence demising enum will cause too many file changes.

Initial Enum class

```
     Class enum Planets{EARTH,MARS,SATURN};

       private static final Planets[] codes={EARTH,MARS,SATURN};

       public static boolean isPlanetPresent(String str){//static Edited 19-09-2013
       for(Palnets planet : codes){
        if(planet.equals(str)){
        return true;
        }
          return false;
      }
```

With the above if we need to check whether NEPTUNE is part of Planets then we need to use `Planets.isPlanetPresent("NEPTUNE")` .

In order to minimize changes, I decided to retain the enum class but as a ordinary class. 
A static array is declared inside the class and is loaded during runtime which reads data from a table in db.

Static alternative I thought of:

```
 Class Planets{

private static String[] codes;

public Planets{
    Spring IOC to connect to db and get the data and place it into codes array( EARTH,MARS,SATURN)
}

public static boolean isPlanetPresent(String str){
    for(String planet : codes){
        if(planet.equals(str)){
        return true;
        }
          return false;
    }
}
```

With the above implementation `Planets.isPlanetPresent("NEPTUNE")` need not be changed in other files.

My question is:

1. Is my implementation correct?
2. Are there any better alternative implementations?

Comment: initial enum is strange

Comment: Your code looks good to me. If you would add the constants at runtime, you should use a Set instead of a string array. If you think multiple threads can modify the Set, use a concurrent Set.

Comment: Agreed its a old code..

Comment: You could use a Set<String> and the contains() method to see if the planet exists.

Comment: Point taken will optimize it..

Answer (score 0):

### Way 1

You could declare an entity (if you use an ORM) with static constant, something like this (with hibernate):

```
public class Planet {

    public static final Planet SATURN = new Planet(1L, "SATURN");

    public static final Planet MARS = new Planet(2L, "MARS");

    // ...

    private static final Planet[] VALUES = { SATURN, MARS /*, ...*/ }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    private Planet(final Long id, final String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Simulates enum#values().
     * 
     * @return list of declared values.
     */
    public static Planet[] values() {
        return VALUES.clone();
    }

    /**
     * Simulates enum#valueOf(String).
     * 
     * @return found {@link Planet} or null.
     */
    @Nullable
    public static Planet valueOf(final String name)
    {
        Planet result = null;
        for (final Planet val : values()) {
            if (val.getName().equals(name)) {
                result = val;
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

### Way 2

Stick to an enum, and use DB "enumerated" datatype to ensure a db change when an enum value is added.